# How would I display a specific object in a array in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I get an API response and I can display all 20 results from the response and all 20 descriptions. I want to display them by index and they are already indexed in the response. I don't know how to select the object in the array of articles and display a specific article.

Here is my response:

[image: API Response]

And here is my code:

```js
    render() {
        let articles = this.state.articles;
        return (
            <div>
                <ExpansionPanel>
                        {articles.map(article => (<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}><Typography>{article.title[0]}</Typography></ExpansionPanelSummary>))}
                    <ExpansionPanelDetails>           
                            {articles.map((article) => (
                                <Typography>{article.description}</Typography>
                            ))}<br />
                    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            </div>
        );
```

//Fixed article title but article description is repeating.

I can specify what title I want to get however when I use `this.state.articles[0].description` I get repeating results in the drop-down.

[image: Repeating Descriptions]

**Correlating code:**

```js
<ExpansionPanel>
                    {articles.map(articles => (<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}><Typography>{this.state.articles[1].title}</Typography></ExpansionPanelSummary>))}         
                    {articles.map((articles) => (<ExpansionPanelDetails><Typography>{this.state.articles[1].description}</Typography></ExpansionPanelDetails>))}<br />
</ExpansionPanel>
```

// Added new snippet

```js
{articles.map((articles, index) => (
                    <div>
                        <ExpansionPanel key={index}>
                            <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}><Typography>{this.state.articles.title}</Typography></ExpansionPanelSummary>       
                            <ExpansionPanelDetails><Typography>{this.state.articles.description}</Typography></ExpansionPanelDetails><br />
                        </ExpansionPanel>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

// Fixed... had to use the property `articles` instead of `this.state.articles`. This fixed the repeat issue and the display issue.

Comment: I've posted an answer that addresses how to get a single element from an array. I think there may be more to your question, however. How do you want to display the element that you select? I mean, what do you want this to look like in the web page. One way to help explain this is to open MS Paint or a similar program and draw a rough example of what you want the page to be.

Comment: i think your question is a javascript related question not react.
if i understand correctly i think you could use this.state.articles[index]

Comment: I want to display a title and when you click it a drop-down with the correlating description is shown.

Comment: @J.Borga edit your question to show how you generated the output in the screenshot

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Added the snippet

Comment: Instead of mapping over the articles array twice, you should only map over it once. See my answer for details.

Comment: <ExpansionPanelDetails><Typography>{this.state.articles.description}</Typography></ExpansionPanelDetails><br /> this seems of no sense in your last snippet

Comment: It's fixed... I needed to use the property `articles.description` instead of `this.state.articles.description`

Comment: if you are not done with answers pls post a use case with sample input and its output you want.

Comment: I'm really bad with react on here because I'm using a stack. However I'll add how I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    <ExpansionPanel>
        {articles.map(article => (
            <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}><Typography>{article.title}</Typography></ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>           
                <Typography>{article.description}</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>))}
    </ExpansionPanel>
</div>
```

It is not completely clear what you want. But what I could guess is, you want something like this

```
index1---summary
--index1 detail hidden or whatever
index2---summary
--index2 detail hidden or whatever
index3---summary
--index3 detail hidden or whatever
```

You can try above code

Comment: The response isn't indexed at the title. I can fetch a specific item using `this.state.articles[0].title` however when I use description it comes up with repeating results.

Comment: You probably need `article.title` instead of `article.title[0]`.

Comment: Do you have complete data at once?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that was a copy paste mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an `<ExpansionPanel>` for each article. This means you need to `map()` over the array like this:

```
render() {
    let articles = this.state.articles;
    return <div>
        {articles.map((article, index) => <ExpansionPanel key={index}>
            ...
         </ExpansionPanel>}
    </div>;
}
```

Now in the place of the `...` in the code example, you can add whatever other components you want, such as `<ExpansionPanelSummary>` or `<ExpansionPanelDetails>`. You can also use any properties of the article such as `article.description`.

Comment: It worked however, when I do `this.state.articles[0].description` It comes up with repeating results.

Comment: I get this `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` when I map them.

Comment: @J.Borga Note that is only a warning. You still should get some output. Did you fill in the `...` from my code? Were you able to get satisfactory results? To fix the warning just add a key with the index from the array as shown in my most recent edit.

Comment: I added a snippet of what I have... I had to add a `<div>` because it needs a parent element. It doesn't come up with any results however. There are tabs but there is no title or description.

Comment: And when I add `this.state.articles[1].title` instead of `this.state.articles.title` it comes up repeating again. However it's only one description per title but there are repeating titles.

Comment: @J.Borga Use `article.title` or `article.description`.

Comment: Wow that went right over my head... thanks haha. I didn't even realize I was still using `this.state` instead of the `article`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the description is repeating is because of the second loop, if you need description from the each article , you will just need to get it as specified by @code-apprentice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588032/5991690), the extra map is not needed as it will give you repeated results except the title since it is on top. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can access specific post using array article[2].title[0]. This will fetch article number 2 from the response.

You code is not working as some issue with response. Please check but this approach will work to fetch second article.

```js
    render() {
        let articles = this.state.articles;
        return (
            <div>
                <ExpansionPanel>
                        {articles.map(article => (<ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}><Typography>{**article[2].title[0]**}</Typography></ExpansionPanelSummary>))}
                    <ExpansionPanelDetails>           
                            {articles.map((article) => (
                                <Typography>{article.description}</Typography>
                            ))}<br />
                    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: Each `article` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Select article in array using articles[2].objectproperty. SO it will become article[2].title

Comment: It does select the 3rd article if I do `articles[2].title` however when I do `articles[2].description` it repeats multiple descriptions.

Comment: `articles[2]` is very different than `article[2]`. You can do either `artciles[2].title` or `article.title`. Since you are mapping over the array, the second one is probably what you want.

Comment: Remove map on articles which is a loop on complete array thats why your seeing all articles. If you want to see specific article use articles[2].description . I you want to show article based on some action then and pass the index(ex. 2 ) dynamically via props and then syntax will be articles[this.props.index].description .